# Find location of a symbol on an image with python

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to locate a specific symbol on my image. For instance take this as an example:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMNAb.png), How would I locate the location of the heart symbol (like button)? Location as in pixels, where the origin of the coordinate system is at the bottom left corner. I would like to to di by using python. Thanks a lot!

PS: the like symbol could change location for any screenshot

Comment: There are two heart symbols, you mean both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a simple constant-size and well defined image, as it seems to be, you could use **template matching**.

In python there's an excellent [*Scikit Image* module](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html).

In brief:

```py
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.feature import match_template
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

image = imread('big_image.jpg')
template = imread('template.jpg')

image_gray = rgb2gray(image)
template_gray = rgb2gray(template)

result = match_template(image_gray, template_gray)
ij = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(result), result.shape)
x, y = ij[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, it was really useful, however I was wondering if there's a faster way to find that heart symbol location. Skimage does a great job at finding it, however it is a bit slow. Any advice?

Comment: Depending on the pixel-size of your template and how distinguishable it is and how accurate you need the location to be, a simple speed up solution might be to down-sample your images before getting the coordinates. 
For example if you down-sample by a factor of 2 in each direction (e.g.`scipy.ndimage.zoom(image_gray, 0.5)` etc) you will likely see ~ 4x speed up and your location will be accurate to the nearest 2 pixels.